# How to resolve this error ? You need to call ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true) in order to pass null parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

In Spring Boot app. I got this error when trying to insert into DB using hibernate stored procedure. The DB table allows nulls and stored procedure parameters allow null, but still getting this error in my RESTful API side.

> Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter named [dateadded] was null. You need to call ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true) in order to pass null parameters.]

Comment: set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing` (application.properties or so...) to `true` **AND** register the parameters "by name", welcome!

Comment: add this property in Hibernate config. file:  <property name="hibernate.proc.param_null_passing">true</property>

Comment: Setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing doesn't work!